# Como encontrar posição do vetor em python

Tags: python, array, lista, lógica

"Escreva um programa que leia 5 números inteiros e os armazene em um vetor. imprima o vetor, o maior elemento e a posição q ele se encontra"
**QUESTÃO EM PYTHON**

Pessoal, consegui tudo menos armazenar e printar a posição do vetor, toda minha lógica de programação veio de C, to iniciando agora em python.

Aqui embaixo onde parei no meu código.

```
'''# Ler números no vetor e imprimir o vetor, maior elemento e a sua posição.'''
vet1 = [int(input('Digite um número: ')) for n in range(5)]
print(vet1)
maior = int(0)
for vet1 in vet1:
    if vet1 > maior:
        maior = vet1
print(maior)
for i in range(5):
    if maior == vet1[i]:
        pos = i
        print(pos)
```

Comment: Integers armazenam os números inteiros e não é um objeto subscrito, por tratar um inteiro como um objeto subscrito, o interpretador passa a mensagem TypeError:

Comment: py tem uma tipagem dinamica, maior =  int(0), poderia ser apenas maior=0..no ultimo loop há uma função chamada len() que retorna o tamanho do vetor (list).. pode usa-lo como for i in range(len(vet1)) e o uso é vet1[i]...sendo i a posição do vetor e vet1[i] o valor. mais detalhe doc https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Eae blz? Então pelo o que eu entendi você precisa achar só a posição do maior numero no vetor. Eu faço assim:

## Procuro o maior numero e armazeno

maior = max(vetor)

## Depois uso o index na variável que armazenei:

print(vetor.index(maior))

Comment: Verdade, faz sentido mesmo, mas também acabei fazendo por outro meio, vou postar aqui: '
vet1 = [int(input('Digite um número: ')) for n in range(5)]
lista1 = list(vet1)
print(lista1)
maior = int(0)
for vet1 in vet1:
    if vet1 > maior:
        maior = vet1
pos = lista1.index(maior)
print(f'Maior valor da lista: {maior}')
print(f'Posicão do maior valor na lista: {pos + 1}') '

Comment: @MatheusHenrique `lista1 = list(vet1)` é desnecessário porque `vet1` já é uma lista. `int(0)` é redundante (zero já é um número inteiro). Se bem que inicializar com zero não funciona se a lista só tiver números negativos, seria mais garantido inicializar com "infinito negativo" (`float('-inf')`), assim quaisquer números digitados serão com certeza maiores que ele. E `for vet1 in vet1` pode até funcionar, mas usar o mesmo nome da lista para a variável do *loop* torna o código bem confuso...
E outra alternativa seria:  https://ideone.com/bjLYFC